# P and N Channel MOSFET Pair? (Drain Tied Driver)

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I have drain-tied two N-Channel MOSFETS because it is the only way to fit them in my (very) small circuit design. The source of the top one goes to VCC and the bottom goes to GND. The design works as it should electrically, but not as I intended. Because of the way MOSFETS work, I can switch on one of the fets to drive the line out high, but the other one then shorts it to GND because although it allows current to flow in both directions, it can only block in one.

My plan is to use a p-channel fet in place of the second one. Should it be enhancement or depletion? Basically all I want is to have one regular N-channel fet and the equivalent of one in exactly the same physical package, only the gate and source are swapped. This will allow me to drive the load both high and low, and my design can fit on the PCB.

Comment: Your P-Channel M4 is upside down.

Comment: See the "CMOS Circuitry" section of the [HCMOS Design Considerations](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scla007) appnote.

Comment: @brhans You're Right! Fixed it.

Comment: @CL. That's what I thought. So if I have two power MOSFET inverters, one output connected with each lead to a dc motor, I could switch the motor direction with digital signals? What if I want to leave the lead floating so I can measure EMF? Don't P Channel fets behave differently than n-channel when the same voltage is applied?

Comment: M4 is still upside down. To have the output floating, disable both FETs (see the inverter with output enable).